# Filebeat vs packetbeat for web traffic analysis

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat, packetbeat

I have a web server and I need to analyze the traffic and find potential anomalies in it. My first idea was to use `filebeat` to take the apache web access logs and pass it to the ELK stack. The nginx web access logs are in the following form:

```
42.236.10.125 - - [19/Dec/2020:15:23:11 +0100] "GET /templates/jp_hotel/css/template.css HTTP/1.1" 200 10004 "http://www.almhuette-raith.at/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.1.0; zh-CN; EML-AL00 Build/HUAWEIEML-AL00) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/57.0.2987.108 baidu.sogo.uc.UCBrowser/11.9.4.974 UWS/2.13.1.48 Mobile Safari/537.36 AliApp(DingTalk/4.5.11) com.alibaba.android.rimet/10487439 Channel/227200 language/zh-CN" "-"
42.236.10.117 - - [19/Dec/2020:15:23:11 +0100] "GET /templates/jp_hotel/css/layout.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1801 "http://www.almhuette-raith.at/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.1.0; zh-CN; EML-AL00 Build/HUAWEIEML-AL00) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/57.0.2987.108 baidu.sogo.uc.UCBrowser/11.9.4.974 UWS/2.13.1.48 Mobile Safari/537.36 AliApp(DingTalk/4.5.11) com.alibaba.android.rimet/10487439 Channel/227200 language/zh-CN" "-"
```

However, I noticed that `packetbeat` also exists, but based on my research I found out that it provides a similar output:

[image]

So my question is what is the difference between the two of them and should I use both? Is there a feature that `packetbeat` has and it might be useful for my case?

Comment: packetbeat and filebeat do not produce a similar output. What makes you think they do?

Comment: @Val Based on what I have studied until now and what I have shown above, I reached to this conclusion. I mean filebeat helps keeping and centralizing logs (in my case apache web access logs) and packetbeat produces the same logs as I can see.

Comment: Packetbeat is a network traffic analyzer, it doesn't produce logs (at least not in the same vein as what Filebeat does, which only tails existing logs produced by other system), but metrics related to packets transitting over the network, they are two different things, which can end up being complimentary when correlated (e.g. by host).

Answer (score 1):

I would use packetbeat if you are reviewing strictly network traffic and NOT logs.
If you are analyzing logs, use Filebeat.
You can use both tools, but make sure to understand what you're trying to have the tool ingest.

Comment: Apart from the fact that I need to perform network traffic in an nginx web server, I also need to save somewhere the web access logs that are produced from the nginx web server. So, I suppose I should use them both? My main question is what kind of metrics can packetbeat offer me that facilitate network traffic monitoring?